# C# : Using this in a constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

In C# is it ok to use this in the constructor? (i.e., is it ok to reference the instance in the constructor)

As a simple example:

```
public class Test{

 public Test()
 {
    Type type = this.GetType()
 }

}
```

Comment: Yes. Take a look here : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ConstructorsInCSharp.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use `this` in the constructor, but not in field initializers.

So this is not valid:

```
class Foo
{
    private int _bar = this.GetBar();

    int GetBar()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

But this is allowed:

```
class Foo
{
    private int _bar;

    public Foo()
    {
        _bar = this.GetBar();
    }

    int GetBar()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public class Test{

 private string strName;
 public Test(string strName)
 {
    this.strName = strName;
 }

}
```

I think is good to use in every part of the class the `this` identifier... Atributes, Methods, Properties, because it gets more allusive to what you are modifying or using, in complex classes or large ones it helps you to know faster what you are using, but as I said, in my point of view.

Comment: `this` is just extra verbosity with no added value to me, but to each their own.

Comment: yes its just allusive like other reserved words like const, readonly, just for the programmer, well and in my example, it is forcely needed when you use a parameter named exactly equal to a global property/attribute, and you dont get confused if you are using a local variable, a paremeter or a global variable with the 'this'.. but as you said to each their own

Comment: I avoid that with an underscore for member variables.  I do not like the `memberVariable` convention just for that reason.  Then I get collisions in method signatures and have to use `this` all over the place.  Also, I don't think you mean to say "Allusive".  Explicit perhaps? :)

Comment: hehe, yeps maybe xD. And you said it, you can get collisions in methods if you dont use it, I think for not having future problems, just use it, it doesn't hurt you a lot, just like 5 characters this. xD